# PHP file_get_contents and stream return warning instead of content

Tags: php, apache, http, url, localhost

I am trying to get the content of a HTTP / HTTPS website.

I have a running XAMPP environment locally with these additions to the php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_include = On
allow_url_fopen = On
```

I tried to get the content with 2 ways:

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
    echo $homepage;
?>
```

also:

```
<?php
    $stream = fopen('http://www.example.com', 'r'))
    {
        echo stream_get_contents($stream);
        fclose($stream);
    }
?>
```

Also when I use the suppression tag "@" in front of fopen or file_get_contents I get warnings all time only saying warning in line XY, where the fopen or file_get_contents line is located. But no content is loaded from the URL..

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Enable `allow_url_fopen`  in your PHP Configuration

Comment: try  $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/'); var_dump($http_response_header); after call

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky isn't allow_url_fopen = On the same, i thought this would enable it because i already did that..  @@Rakesh Sharma .. same warnings as before it doesn't come to the output because there must be an error before that is not shown..

Comment: after each change in your php.ini .. you should restart your apache

Comment: @LeoBali I did restart the apache server after the edits in the php.ini

Comment: @FlorianChrometz can you paste the real **url** ?

Comment: https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/items.json there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with cURL.

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```